# Get Qt to use the native Windows copy file widget

Tags: qt

Excusing the actual folders used as an example, I want to achieve the following two widgets in Qt (the backend is similar to files, but not exactly filesystem files):
[folder-replace-dialog](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/9512/folderreplace.jpg) and [copy-file-dialog](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/9906/filecopyx.jpg)

I know Qt can do the native save-file widget (using `QFileDialog` static methods), but can it do the folder replace/file copy dialogs as well? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to call the Windows [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164(VS.85).aspx) directly for this.  It should be possible whether your using gcc or the MS C++ compiler.  You'll need to fill in the `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` but that shouldn't pose too much of a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, my objects are not `file system object`s. They are very similar (in fact they do represent a directory structure) but are stored virtually so windows will not recognize them as file system objects.